# How to map IGrouping<T, K> to IGrouping<T, V> using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a sample object with some properties

```
public class MyObject
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

I used the `GroupBy` Linq method on a collection and now have a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyObject>>`. I want to map each group to be of type `IGrouping<string, string>` by picking `myObject.Foo + myObject.Bar` from the object class. So the final result would be `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>`.

I tried to start with a `Select`

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, MyObject>> oldCollection = null;
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>> newCollection = oldCollection
    .Select(oldGroup =>
    {
        IGrouping<string, string> newGroup = null;

        // pick the key from the oldGroup via oldGroup.Key

        // map the values from oldGroup to strings, sample code:
        // newGroup.Values = oldGroup.Select(myObject => myObject.Foo + myObject.Bar);

        return newGroup;
    });
```

how can I map `oldGroup` to `newGroup` in that statement?

Comment: Can't you `GroupBy` directly to a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, string>>`? The `.GroupBy` has an overload just to do it, like `.GroupBy(x => x.Foo, x => new { x.Foo + x.Bar });`

Comment: yes, that sounds pretty awesome! Let my try that

Comment: yes, that solved it :) feel free to post your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to regroup everything a solution is to "unroll" the grouping (with `.SelectMany`) and the "regroup" it.

```
var regrouped = grouped
    .SelectMany(x => x, (x, y) => new { x.Key, Sum = y.Foo + y.Bar })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum);
```

Clearly perhaps you could simply have built the grouping "correctly"

```
var grouped = collection.GroupBy(x => x.Foo, x => new { x.Foo + x.Bar });
```

There is an overload of `.GroupBy` just for that, with the second parameter that sets the "content" of each group element.